# DynamoDB:PutItem calls silently ignored

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Lambda function bound to CodeBuild notifications; a Lambda instance writes details of the notification that triggered it to a DynamoDB table (BillingMode `PAY_PER_REQUEST`)

Each CodeBuild notification spawns an independent Lambda instance. A CodeBuild build can spawn 7-8 separate notifications/Lambda instances, many of which often happen simultaneously.

The Lambda function uses `DynamoDB:PutItem` to put details of the notification to DynamoDB. What I find is that out of 7-8 notifications in a 30 second period, sometimes all 7-8 get written to DynamoDB, but sometimes it can be as low as 0-1; many calls to `DynamoDB:PutItem` simply seem to be "ignored".

*Why is this happening?*

My guess is that DynamoDB simply shouldn't be accessed by multiple Lambda instances in this way; that best practice is to push the updates to a SQS queue bound to a separate Lambda, and have that separate Lambda write many updates to DynamoDB as part of a transaction.

Is that right? Why might parallel independent calls to `DynamoDB:PutItem` fail silently?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB uses a web endpoint and for that reason it can handle any number of concurrent connections, so the issue is not with how many Lambdas are writing.

I typically see this happen when users do not allow the Lambda to wait until the API requests are complete and the container gets shut down prematurely. I would first check your code and ensure that your lambda is staying alive for all items to be processed, you can do this by adding some simple logging in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a good use case for Step Functions.

As much as Lambda functions are great to glue between services, they have their overheads and their limitations. With Step Functions, you can call directly to DynamoDB:PutItem, and you can handle various scenarios and flows, such as Async calls. These flows are possible to implement in a Lambda function, however with less visibility and with less traceability.

BTW, you can also call a Lambda function from Step Functions, however, I recommend you to try and use the direct service call to maximize the benefits of the Step Functions service.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I had a separate issue which was messing up some of the range keys and causing updates to "fail" silently. But thx for the tip regarding timeouts